# Joint and individual probability independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If (A,B,C) is independent of D, are the following true?

- A then also independent of D
- B then also independent of D
- C then also independent of D

Comment: Yes, and this is obvious from the definition of joint independence. Any idea about what this definition might be?

Comment: The joint independence model implies that two variables are jointly independent of a third.

Comment: graphically if A,B,C forms a line/graph and is independent of D, then any point of the line should be independent of D. But what about @Ilya's argument?

Comment: Definition please, not vague paraphrases.

Comment: Is it `P(∩i∈I Ai) = Πi∈I P(Ai) for any subset of I ⊆ {1, . . . n}` ?

Comment: i.e. A collection of events `A1, A2, AI,..` are independent, if the the probability of event `A1∩A2∩...∩AI` = the product of `P(A1)...P(AI)`.

Comment: Using this definition, the fact that if (A,B,C,D) is independent then, say, (A,D) is independent, is rather clear, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the symmetry of the argument, it is equivalent to ask whether independence of $A\cap B \cap C$ and $D$ implies the independence of $A$ and $D$. It's not true: suppose that $A = B = D$ and $C = D^c$. Then $A\cap B\cap C = \emptyset\perp D$, but none of $A,B,C$ is itself independent of $D$.